# Loop over multiple groups and create individual scatter plots in R

Tags: r, loops, group-by, subset, scatter-plot

Hello all very new to R and coding in general. My problem is exactly the same as this user`s
[loop over groups and create plot for each one R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52317318/loop-over-groups-and-create-plot-for-each-one-r) but unlike the iris dataset that has only 3 groups under species, my data frame has ~1000 groups.

Basically, I want to have individual scatter plots for every **Protein** (~1000) with each individual points as the **Peptides** (**x= Peptides, y= Ratio**).

I tried both responses that was provided in the question above, but neither worked.
The second code in the question generated individual plots for each protein but plotted all the peptides in the dataframe (essentially plotting the same scatter plot over and over again, with changing protein name) as shown here--->[How my current output looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7cQe.png)

**EDIT**
Here's a snapshot of my actual dataframe
Show in New Window

```
structure(list(Peptides = c("LAMB1.52_.R..YSDIEPSTEGEVIFR..A.", 
"LAMB1.54_.R..YVVLPRPVCFEK..G.", "LAMB1.55_.K..YYYAVYDMVVR..G.", 
"LAMB1.56_.K..YYYAVYDMVVR..G.", "LAMC1_.K..AFDITYVR..L.", "LAMC1.3_.R..ATAESASECLPCDCNGR..S.", 
"LAMC1.4_.R..CDCHALGSTNGQCDIR..T.", "LAMC1.5_.R..CDQCEENYFYNR..S.", 
"LAMC1.6_.K..CLPFFNDR..P.", "LAMC1.7_.K..CLPFFNDRPWR..R.", "LAMC1.8_.K..CLPFFNDRPWRR..A.", 
"LAMC1.9_.K..CIYNTAGFYCDR..C.", "LAMC1.10_.R..CQPGFHSLTEAGCR..P.", 
"LAMC1.11_.R..CRENFFR..L.", "LAMC1.13_.K..DNVEGFNCER..C.", "LAMC1.14_.K..DVDQNLMDR..L.", 
"LAMC1.15_.K..DVDQNLMDR..L.", "LAMC1.16_.K..DYEDLREDMR..G.", 
"LAMC1.17_.K..DYEDLREDMR..G.", "LAMC1.18_.K..DYEDLREDMRGK..E.", 
"LAMC1.19_.K..DYEDLREDMRGK..E.", "LAMC1.20_.R..EDGPWIPYQYYSGSCENTYSK..A.", 
"LAMC1.21_.R..EGFVGNR..C.", "LAMC1.22_.R..EGFVGNRCDQCEENYFYNR..S.", 
"LAMC1.24_.K..FHTSRPESFAIYK..R.", "LAMC1.25_.R..HKQEADDIVR..V.", 
"LAMC1.27_.R..KQDDADQDMMMAGMASQAAQEAEINAR..K.", "LAMC1.28_.R..KQDDADQDMMMAGMASQAAQEAEINAR..K.", 
"LAMC1.29_.R..KQDDADQDMMMAGMASQAAQEAEINAR..K.", "LAMC1.30_.R..KQDDADQDMMMAGMASQAAQEAEINAR..K.", 
"LAMC1.32_.R..KQDDADQDMMMAGMASQAAQEAEINARK..A.", "LAMC1.35_.K..KQEAAIMDYNR..D.", 
"LAMC1.36_.K..KQEAAIMDYNR..D.", "LAMC1.39_.R..LHEATDYPWR..P.", 
"LAMC1.40_.K..LLNNLTSIK..I.", "LAMC1.41_.R..LNTFGDEVFNDPK..V.", 
"LAMC1.42_.K..IRGTYSER..S.", "LAMC1.43_.R..LSAEDLVLEGAGLR..V.", 
"LAMC1.44_.R..LTGECLK..C.", "LAMC1.45_.K..NISQDLEK..Q.", "LAMC1.51_.R..QDIAVISDSYFPR..Y.", 
"LAMC1.52_.K..QEAAIMDYNR..D.", "LAMC1.53_.K..QEAAIMDYNR..D.", 
"LAMC1.55_.R..RATAESASECLPCDCNGR..S.", "LAMC1.57_.R..SQECYFDPELYR..S.", 
"LAMC1.58_.R..SWPGCQECPACYR..L.", "LAMC1.59_.K..SYYYAISDFAVGGR..C.", 
"LAMC1.61_.K..TAAEEALR..K.", "LAMC1.62_.R..TGQCECQPGITGQHCER..C.", 
"LAMC1.63_.R..TREDGPWIPYQYYSGSCENTYSK..A.", "LAMC1.64_.R..VSVPLIAQGNSYPSETTVK..Y.", 
"LAMC1.66_.R..YFIAPAK..F.", "FLNA.1_.K..AGNNMLLVGVHGPR..T.", 
"FLNA.2_.K..AGNNMLLVGVHGPR..T.", "FLNA.3_.K..AGVAPLQVK..V.", 
"FLNA.6_.K..ATCAPQHGAPGPGPADASK..V.", "FLNA.8_.R..AYGPGIEPTGNMVK..K.", 
"FLNA.13_.K..DAGEGLLAVQITDPEGKPK..K.", "FLNA.16_.R..DVDIIDHHDNTYTVK..Y.", 
"FLNA.17_.R..EAGAGGLAIAVEGPSK..A.", "FLNA.18_.R..EATTEFSVDAR..A."
), Ratio = c(1.056754467, 1.174922122, 1.053785481, 1.125303543, 
1.124986981, 1.033582206, 0.999034319, 1.06338514, 1.14573856, 
1.168731217, 0.803946964, 1.070001334, 0.79258407, 0.971011335, 
1.046705546, 0.853712706, 0.90907656, 1.078730919, 1.155442728, 
1.64320038, 1.271964691, 1.167744801, 1.107760911, 1.764000051, 
1.287814849, 1.3053024, 0.809893271, 0.937671629, 1.02568349, 
0.975795003, 1.26120622, 0.669929057, 0.860244941, 0.953860383, 
0.852241097, 1.00511006, 1.157047594, 2.365514653, 1.367842325, 
0.950098923, 1.180357859, 1.074772699, 1.043318915, 0.97532573, 
1.106755776, 1.035721353, 1.089302473, 0.872753968, 1.16134958, 
0.986453823, 0.972356049, 1.134263144, 0.564740889, 0.596272445, 
0.837378424, 0.799958396, 0.668971848, 0.595255023, 0.657884455, 
0.856494001, 0.883430995), Protein = c("LAMB1", "LAMB1", "LAMB1", 
"LAMB1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", 
"LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", 
"LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", 
"LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", 
"LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", 
"LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", 
"LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", "LAMC1", 
"FLNA", "FLNA", "FLNA", "FLNA", "FLNA", "FLNA", "FLNA", "FLNA", 
"FLNA")), row.names = 40:100, class = "data.frame")
```

This is the code that I ran, same as the suggested answer in the post I referred to above.

```
pep_df<-read.csv("Peptides.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE)
    protein_list<-unique(pep_df$Protein)
    
    pep_plot <- function(x,y,z) {
      ggplot(data=pep_df, aes_string(x=x,y=y, colour=z)) +
        geom_point(shape = 21, aes_string(fill = z), colour = "black", size =2)
    }
    
    map(protein_list, ~peptide_plot("Peptides", "Ratio",.x))
```

after running this code now I am now getting this error, cannot even generate the repeating scatter plots anymore.

```
    Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'LAMB1' not found
```

Thanks again, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should show the code that created your plot. You have not applied the examples correctly. They should have been able to give you properly separated plots.

Comment: Please share a little bit of sample data in a copy/pasteable format - we can't try to run code on a screenshot. `dput()` is a great function for making a copy/pasteable version of data, `dput(your_data[1:20, ])` for the first 20 rows. And, as IRTFM says, please also share the code you tried so that we (a) have something to start with and (b) can help debug it.

Comment: HI ALL! I edited my question to include all relevant info, I tried to run my code again and I cannot even generate the repeating scatter plots. The first time around, I converted my "Protein" column to as.factor() --seeing that in the example iris dataset when checking the class() of "Species" it returned said "factor" thinking that it would fix it, and that's when i got the repeating scatterplots for each protein. Apologies if this is long-winded and confusing.